# Preventing Visual Studio Designer from Setting Text Property on Creation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've got a problem with Visual Studio Designer's convention of setting the text in a TextBox to the name of the control.  I've got a control that accepts a Social Security Number, and the Text property is overridden so as to throw an exception if the text is not in the correct format (e.g. 123-45-6789 or 123456789).  When I try to use the control in the designer, this exception is thrown because Visual Studio is trying to name the control cssnTextBox1.  Is there an attribute I can place on the Text property to prevent the designer from setting it?

Comment: Why aren't you using a validator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this discussion: how to detect design time in C# control.

http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2005/04/11/1246.aspx

You need to disable the Text property validation, if control's container is in design mode.